# Slow running query

Tags: java, multithreading, ibatis, apache-commons-dbcp

We have a query that's taking 3 hours to finish. This wasn't a problem before. Before, the code that calls this query is deployed on weblogic and uses the latter's own connection pool manager.

Now since the process occupies a lot of memory, we pulled this code out and made it run on its own heap space. The request to call the query is made via jms. I also noticed that the connection pool manager we are using is dbcp using its default settings (max connections = 8, min connections =0). The jms client is multithreaded.

When we executed the query via an interface (TOAD), it only takes 2 seconds so from here I have ruled out "blaming" the database.

I was wondering what steps I could take from here to find the bottle neck. Maybe something with the connection pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a tool like VisualVM or a thread dump to check what are your threads doing. Are they just waiting for some IO operation to complete? Is there some poorly synchronized code waiting much longer than needed? Maybe even a deadlock that stops after a three-hour (or three one-hour) timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I find it's always worthwhile to fall back to the most basic Java performance tool at your disposal: thread dumps.  There are lots of ways to get a thread dump:

- If you have a console, use ctrl-break (win), or ctrl-\ (*nix)
- jstack
- jconsole and the thread tabs or available mbeans to cause a dump

Look at what your program is doing.  Take these periodically.  There are tools to help you look at big thread dumps as well like the [Thread Dump Analyzer](http://www.java.net/project/tda-thread-dump-analyzer) or [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html).

You can also use jconsole or Visual VM to look at this interactively but I think a well-developed talent for reading raw dumps will serve you well.